# split a string and print only numbers from an alphanumeric string

Tags: string, split, tcl

I am a newbee in Tcl. I have a certain string "code_lines_part2021vol32i8mn.txt" and I want to print only the numbers in the format "2021 32 8" How can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this... Idea is to remove all characters other than numbers with `regsub command` and replace by space :

```
set your_string "code_lines_part2021vol32i8mn.txt"
regsub -all -nocase {[._a-z]} $your_string { } newstring
lassign $newstring num_1 num_2 num_3
puts "result = $num_1 $num_2 $num_3"
# result = 2021 32 8
```

This would probably be easier with the `regexp command` but I haven't figured it out yet.
documentation : [regsub](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regsub.html), [lassign](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lassign.html) and [regexp](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regexp.html) (if you want try)

Comment: thanks @Mkn for the answer but I am using Tcl version 8.4 and lassign doest not seem to work on it. It gives error "invalid command name : lassign" Is there any other way? I cannot update the Tcl version due to shared libraries.

Comment: @sing20 you can use `foreach {num_1 num_2 num_3} $newstring {}` instead

Comment: thanks a lot. both method worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an old Tcl to test with, but try this:

```sh
set numbers [regexp -all -inline {\d+} $string]
puts [join $numbers]
```

Comment: You don't need that `join`; non-empty digit sequences are always nice words.

Comment: Well, I've trained myself that lists are lists and strings are strings and never the twain shall meet.